# take data from 2 tables in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have started learning Zend Framework for 3 days and get stuck
I have a webpage that allow user to choose the brand of phone: Apple and Samsung in a select box. After choosing, the data from mySQL will be showed below (for each brand, the data will be different). Now I want to implement a search function that will list all the match result (counted for every table). In PHP based this will be easy to use mysql query `LIKE`but now in Zend Framework I have no ideal what should be done. Here is my code so far but it is not working:

index.phtml

```
<script>
    function change(){
        document.getElementById("brand").submit();

    }

</script>
<h3>Choose your brand</h3>
<form id="brand" method="post">
<select name="a" onchange="change();">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="apple" >Apple</option>
    <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>

</select>
</form>
<h3>Choose your product or search for your devices  </h3>
<form id="search" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter device name">
    <input type="submit" name="subsearch">
</form>
<p><table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Manage</th>
    </tr>

     <?php 
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['a'] = $_POST['a'];
        if($_POST['a'] == 'apple'){
        foreach ($this->apple as $apple):
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $apple['id'] . ""; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $apple['name'] . ""; ?></td>
                <td colspan="2"><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => $apple['id'])) ?>"> Edit </a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'deleteapp', 'id' => $apple['id'])) ?>"> Delete </a></td>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </p></table>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'showform'), 'show') ?>">Add new devices</a><?php } ?>
     <?php 
        if($_POST['a'] == 'samsung'){
        foreach ($this->samsung as $samsung):
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $samsung['id'] . ""; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $samsung['name'] . ""; ?></td>
                <td colspan="2"><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => $samsung['id'])) ?>"> Edit </a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'deletesam', 'id' => $samsung['id'])) ?>"> Delete </a></td>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </p></table>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'showf'), 'show') ?>">Add new devices</a><?php } ?>
```

IndexController:

```
 public function searchAction() {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
        $table = $this->getDbTable();
        $select = $table->select();
        $select->where('name LIKE ?', $userName . '%');
        $rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this part

```
$select->where('name LIKE ?', $userName . '%');
```

like this *(but please dont forget to replace tables {tablename, anothertable} and columns {name, surname, email} with those you use in your project)*

```
    $select->from('tablename', 'name')
    ->where('tablename.name LIKE ?', $userName . '%')
    ->join('anothertable', 'anothertable.name = tablename.name', array('name', 'surname', 'email'))
    ->order("anothertable.name ASC");
```

*->join('**anothertable**', '**anothertable.name = tablename.name**', **array('name', 'surname', 'email')**)**->order("anothertable.name ASC")**;*

`anothertable` - name of the table you are joining
`anothertable.name = tablename.name` - the criteria which will add columns from appropriate rows of anothertable
`array('name', 'surname', 'email')` - name of columns query will add
`->order("anothertable.name ASC")` - this will say which column to sort

here is more info http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html
hope this helps you.